# Will there be any performance improvement if I upgrade the grails version

Tags: grails

I have a grails app built on grails 1.3.7.

1. My app is pretty slow and I'm trying to figure out the hungry blocks in my code.
2. On the other side I'm thinking whether upgrading to latest grails version will add to the performance of my app. will that do any good for my app?
3. Will upgrading just the plugins keeping the grails as it is will help?

And if you know any plugins or tweaks I can add to improve its performance, please suggest.

Thank  you.

Comment: there is no silver bullet.  you need to measure, _what_ makes the application slow (define metrics for what is "slow" and then find the biggest bottlenecks and only attack them).  could as well be your database, your provider, the alignment of the stars.  a new grails version will most likely give a random improvement, but e.g. might enable you to use `@(Grails)CompileStatic` -- but to apply it, you need to know _where_.  Also condsider modularizing your app or just get a faster machine.  Even with more infos about your situation I doubt anybody will be able to give an answer.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply! To upgrade my grails version, should I follow some procedure or is dat as easy as to run a grails command?

Answer (score 0):

Well in general you need to remember a few things.

1. Grails app runs over groovy, and groovy returns a java code at the end that runs on the jvm. So it will always be slower than the pure java code.
2. There is a vast difference between the runtime required for a java code and a groovy code. eg for loop is much efficient than each method of groovy.
3. Dynamic finders and the meta programming slows down a grails app even more, since all the methods and finders are created at runtime.

[Grails vs Java comparision](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-7-vs-groovy-21)

1. In order to speed by your app try using `@CompileStatic` annotation  that can speed up your app to a good extent. This will disable your dynamic finders and meta programming. So use it wisely and in classes where you do not require then. You can use it both at method level and class level. BUt to use this you need to upgrade to grails 2.0 version
2. Other measures you can take is to avoid using groovy functions like each etc and use java counterparts like while, for etc

Comment: But if we avoid dynamic finders and groovy each loops, don't we miss out the beauty of grails which we chose that for!

Comment: there is `GrailsCompileStatic` http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/staticTypeCheckingAndCompilation.html;  also this is generic advice, you should apply _after_ finding the bottlenecks